# Use find_next_sibling() for specific class value only

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of `p` elements in a page of `HTML` and using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the `HTML` page. The page is an index of an online book. What I need to do is create a nested `JSON` structure where there is currently none, as some terms of the index are children of a single term.
So you can think of the index like this:

```
parent term
    child term
    child term
    child term
parent term
parent term
```

However, the HTML is not nested, it is listed in all `<p>` tags, like below. As you can see, the term `Action(s)` is a parent term and has 8 children. Then the next parent term is `Actionable Insights` and has 0 children. I have a loop that iterates through each `<p>` tag, and need to nest the children under the parent in the JSON file. So I can't use `find_next_siblings()` (plural), because it will just get all `<p>` tags indiscriminately. But if I can find a way to use `find_next_sibling()` (singular), but only those with the `'class': 'index2'`, and add them to a list, then I can add that list as a child to the parent term. At least, this is my logic so far.

```
<h2>A</h2>
    <p class="index1">Acceptance of insights, merit-based, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_3">3</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Accuracy of data, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_125">125</a>, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_126">126</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Action(s):</p>
    <p class="index2">of audience, “so what?” question about, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_133">133</a>–135</p>
    <p class="index2">communicating to turn insights into, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_10">10</a>–12</p>
    <p class="index2">in deriving value from analytics, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_11">11</a>–12</p>
    <p class="index2">driving, <i>see</i> Driving action</p>
    <p class="index2">empowering audience to act, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_178">178</a>–180</p>
    <p class="index2">in 4D Framework, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_128">128</a>–132</p>
    <p class="index2">inspired by insights, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_9">9</a>–10</p>
    <p class="index2">as objective of communication, <a href="c02.xhtml#Page_36">36</a>, <a href="c02.xhtml#Page_37">37</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Actionable insights, <a href="c03.xhtml#Page_51">51</a>, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_132">132</a>–135</p>
    <p class="index1">Additive annotations, <a href="c08.xhtml#Page_244">244</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Aggregating data, <a href="c08.xhtml#Page_232">232</a></p>
    <p class="index1">AGT/HEED, <a href="c04.xhtml#Page_108">108</a>–109</p>
    <p class="index1">Aha Moment:</p>
    <p class="index2">connecting Hook and, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_176">176</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in Data Storytelling Arc, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_163">163</a>–167</p>
    <p class="index2">in data trailers, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_181">181</a>, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_182">182</a>, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_292">292</a>–293</p>
    <p class="index2">identified in storyboarding, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_172">172</a>–173</p>
    <p class="index2">initial interest generated by, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_178">178</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in manufacturing gross margin story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_295">295</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in Rosling story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_273">273</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in US education system story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_286">286</a></p>
```

The problem, however, is I can't figure out the logic for it. It's complicated, because I need recursion as well. But I keep getting `NoneType` errors (noted below). The rest of the code works, if I take out that codeblock I'm stuck on. But how can I use BeautifulSoup to only get the next `<p>` tag with a class of `index2`? At least the children are identified as `index2`. I just want to avoid scanning the entire document every time I need a few children terms. It seems like it should be straight-forward, but have not had luck. Thanks for your help.

**MY CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# convert html to bs4 object
def bs4_convert(file):
    with open(file, encoding='utf8') as fp:
        html = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    return html

# create a tag
def p_parser(el, link_prefix):
    tags = []
    for p in el:
        tag = {
            'tag': p.text,
            'definition': '',
            'source': [{'title': link.text, 'href': link_prefix + link['href']} for link in p.find_all('a', recursive=False)]
        }
        # add all child terms of a parent term to a list
```

STUCK HERE, THIS CODEBLOCK KEEPS GETTING SNAGGED ON NONETYPE ERROR, SAYING `p.find_next_sibling('p')['class']` IS NOT SUBSCRIPTABLE. EVEN THOUGH I CHECK FOR NONE.

```
        children = []
        if(p.find_next_sibling('p') is not None):
            while(p.find_next_sibling('p')['class'] == ['index2']):
                next_child = p.find_next_sibling('p')
                if(next_child is not None):
                    children.append(next_child)
                    p = next_child
                else:
                    break
                
        # make child tags
        tag['children'] = p_parser(children, link_prefix)

        tags.append(tag)

    return tags

# loop through all indices
def html_parser(html, link_prefix):
    tags = []
    # extract index
    html.find('section', {'role': "doc-index"})
    # iterate over every indented letter in index
    letters = html.find_all('section')
    for letter in letters:
        tags += p_parser(letter.find_all('p'), link_prefix)

    return tags

# add the course name as parent to all tags
def add_course_tag(course_name, tags):
    complete_tags = {
        'tag': course_name,
        'definition': '',
        'source': tags
    }

    return complete_tags

# write tags to JSON file
def write_to_json(course_name, tags):
    # Serializing json 
    json_object = json.dumps(tags, indent = 4)

    # Writing to course_name.json
    with open(course_name + '_tags.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)

def main():
    # course information for the book
    course = {
        'course': 'data_storytelling', # exact course name
        'file': 'data_storytelling.html', # the html file you extracted
        'parse_type': 'index'
    }

    # this link prefix should be the same for all pages of one book
    prefix_id = 'effective-data-storytelling/9781119615712'
    link_prefix = 'https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/' + prefix_id + '/'

    tags = []
    # parse the html
    html = bs4_convert(course['file'])
    # create tags
    tags = html_parser(html, link_prefix)
    # add course name as outermost tag
    tags = add_course_tag(course['course'], tags)
    # write results to json file
    write_to_json(course['course'], tags)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT:**
I tried this code, but it would not stop running in the command line (and nothing new printed to the JSON file).

```
# create a tag
def p_parser(el, link_prefix):
    tags = []
    for p in el:
        tag = {
            'tag': p.text,
            'definition': '',
            'source': [{'title': link.text, 'href': link_prefix + link['href']} for link in p.find_all('a', recursive=False)]
        }
        # add all child terms of a parent term to a list
        children = []
        for child in p.next_siblings:
            if child.name == 'p' and 'index2' not in child['class']:
                break
            elif child.name == 'p' and 'index2' in child['class']:
                children.append(child) 

        tags.append(tag)
        # make child tags
        tag['children'] = p_parser(children, link_prefix)

    return tags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are close to your goal, just some little adjustment to do - While iterating check for `tag.name` as well as its class and break if it is not a `<p>` with class containing `index2`:

```
children = []

for c in p.next_siblings:
    if c.name == 'p' and 'index2' not in c['class']:
        break
    elif c.name == 'p' and 'index2' in c['class']:
        children.append(c)
```

#### Example

Just to demonstrate, but I believe you would adapt it to your code.

```
import requests,bs4
html='''
<h2>A</h2>
    <p class="index1">Acceptance of insights, merit-based, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_3">3</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Accuracy of data, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_125">125</a>, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_126">126</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Action(s):</p>
    <p class="index2">of audience, “so what?” question about, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_133">133</a>–135</p>
    <p class="index2">communicating to turn insights into, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_10">10</a>–12</p>
    <p class="index2">in deriving value from analytics, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_11">11</a>–12</p>
    <p class="index2">driving, <i>see</i> Driving action</p>
    <p class="index2">empowering audience to act, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_178">178</a>–180</p>
    <p class="index2">in 4D Framework, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_128">128</a>–132</p>
    <p class="index2">inspired by insights, <a href="c01.xhtml#Page_9">9</a>–10</p>
    <p class="index2">as objective of communication, <a href="c02.xhtml#Page_36">36</a>, <a href="c02.xhtml#Page_37">37</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Actionable insights, <a href="c03.xhtml#Page_51">51</a>, <a href="c05.xhtml#Page_132">132</a>–135</p>
    <p class="index1">Additive annotations, <a href="c08.xhtml#Page_244">244</a></p>
    <p class="index1">Aggregating data, <a href="c08.xhtml#Page_232">232</a></p>
    <p class="index1">AGT/HEED, <a href="c04.xhtml#Page_108">108</a>–109</p>
    <p class="index1">Aha Moment:</p>
    <p class="index2">connecting Hook and, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_176">176</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in Data Storytelling Arc, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_163">163</a>–167</p>
    <p class="index2">in data trailers, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_181">181</a>, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_182">182</a>, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_292">292</a>–293</p>
    <p class="index2">identified in storyboarding, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_172">172</a>–173</p>
    <p class="index2">initial interest generated by, <a href="c06.xhtml#Page_178">178</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in manufacturing gross margin story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_295">295</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in Rosling story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_273">273</a></p>
    <p class="index2">in US education system story, <a href="c09.xhtml#Page_286">286</a></p>
'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

# this link prefix should be the same for all pages of one book
prefix_id = 'effective-data-storytelling/9781119615712'
link_prefix = 'https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/' + prefix_id + '/'

data = []

for p in soup.select('p.index1'):
    tag = {
            'tag': p.text,
            'definition': '',
            'source': [{'title': link.text, 'href': link_prefix + link['href']} for link in p.find_all('a', recursive=False)],
            'children':[]
        }
    
    for c in p.next_siblings:
        if c.name == 'p' and 'index1' in c['class']:
            break
        elif c.name == 'p' and 'index2' in c['class']:
            tag['children'].append({
                'tag': c.text,
                'definition': '',
                'source': [{'title': link.text, 'href': link_prefix + link['href']} for link in c.find_all('a', recursive=False)],
            })
    data.append(tag)
    
data
```

### EDIT

```
#create tag
def create_tag(p, link_prefix):
    tag = {
        'tag': p.text,
        'definition': '',
        'source': [{'title': link.text, 'href': link_prefix + link['href']} for link in p.find_all('a', recursive=False)]
    }
return tag

#parse p and p children
def p_parser(el, link_prefix):
    tags = []
    for p in el:
        tag = create_tag(p, link_prefix)
        # add all child terms of a parent term to a list
        children = []
        for child in p.next_siblings:
            if child.name == 'p' and 'index2' not in child['class']:
                break
            elif child.name == 'p' and 'index2' in child['class']:
                if child is not None:
                    children.append(create_tag(child, link_prefix)) 
       
        # make child tags
        if children:
            tag['children'] = children

        # add any parent tags to tags
        tags.append(tag)

    return tags
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, though I run it and it never stops running. I will add the new function to my post under the EDIT heading if you wanted to see how I added it.

Comment: Think you should remove the lines `# make child tags    tag['children'] = p_parser(children, link_prefix)` from your edit and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately that line is needed, it's the only one that adds the children list inside the parent tag. The idea is to create child tags that are just like the parent tags, but the list of child tags should go nested in the parent tag as `'children': [tags]`. Not all index entries have children, so the code snippet is there just in case.

Comment: Does `p.next_siblings` iterate through the entire document of `<p>` tags? That's the problem I kept coming up against with other code. I'm trying to find a way to only iterate through the next few lines as indicated by a condition, if the class is `index2`.

Comment: Added an EDIT to my answer, that shows the solution based on your original code, replace your p_parser function with these both, cause you could not call the p_parser with child elements again, that will cause the infinit loop.

Comment: Looks good, but when I run the code with the new snippets, I get the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`. I know some `<p>` tags are `None`, is this error about that?

Comment: The error shows for line `tag['children'] = children`.

Comment: Thanks for your update you can check for children `if children: tag['children'] = children` edited the section.

Comment: There was no change. I also added a None check to the `elif` to prevent a None child from being added to the list of children, but didn't matter. Hmm, this is strange. I'll add my code to my original post so you can double check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240847/discussion-between-hedgehog-and-azurespot).